# Вопрос по bootstrap и html

Tags: html, bootstrap

Цель: Отображать блок только на больших экранах, не грузить изображение которое внутри блока на маленьких экранах и центрировать изображение по горизонтали и вертикали.

```
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-xxl-block">
            <img src="My JPG.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="My Alt">
        </div>
```

Мне удавалось центрировать так:

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Но когда я решил что мне надо отображать изображение только на больших экранах, с использованием классов `d-none` `d-lg-block` `d-xl-block` `d-xxl-block` центрирование перестало работать.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте не `d-{breakpoint}-block`, а `d-{breakpoint}-flex`

[Display property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: Спасибо! Блок скрывается, а вот как не грузить img на маленьких экранах, когда блок скрыт.